# How many nonsurjective functions $f: A \to A$ are there if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I saw some duplicates, but all are from $A$ to $B$ with other groups of numbers and I can't match it to mine.

> How many nonsurjective functions $f: A \to A$ are there if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

The answer is $3005$. Question is, how do I get to it?

I wanted to try to understand it, so I wanted to know if there is any formula to calculate the surjective functions and from there, I can somehow calculate the nonsurjective functions myself and get to $3005$.  What I thought to do: calculate the number of total functions I can do with $A \times A$, which is $3125$.  Find out the number of surjective functions and just remove them.   I mean: nonsurjective functions = Total functions minus surjective functions.
But the question is, how do I find the total of surjective functions?

Edit: Please use basic tools, as I haven't learnt lot of formulas and such... I saw on other topics stuff I could have never dreamt of seeing...

Comment: since both sets are finite and equal, if you want the function to be surjective it must be bijective and the number of bijections between finite sets is $|A|!$

Comment: What definition of surjective are you working on? And how did you calculate $3125$ for the total number of functions $f: A \to A$? These are useful things to include in your question.

Comment: @Marcos Question, why does it have to be bijective ( i checked google translate, I hope its what I think it is )? actually it works, because the Power of A=5!=120, its actually the answer, 3125-120=3005. But why does it have to be bijective?

Comment: @joseville what do you mean definition? surjeective is surjective no? I checked google translate and wiki to write it in english lol. 3125 is 5^5, total function I can make with A on A ( I saw the total functions I can make with N on N is N^N, this is how I got to it ).

Comment: notice that you want to define a function $f:A\to A$ so you have to set $5$ values ($f(1),\dots,f(5)$) each one has $5$ possiblities, but you want to cover all $5$ values, thus the only option is that each $f(i)$ takes a different value, thus $f$ is injective too.

Comment: @Marcos Hmm, I have a little problem with the English, but lets see...
5 values of f(1) to f(5) ( right ). each one has 5 possibilities ( also right ). The last part I didn't really understand... what is injective? translation makes it as throwing something...

Comment: Injective = one-to-one

Comment: @Gregory oh ok, but how does this help me with the question?
According to how I understand Marcos, each function has 5 possibilites, but there are 5 values, so its one to one, but to how he says, its like its 25 possibilites... or I didnt understand correctly.

Comment: You are correct that there are $5^5$ functions $f: A \to A$, of which $5!$ are surjective, so $5^5 - 5! = 3005$ are not surjective.  You can write your own answer to the question.  Grammar:  Write nonsurjective for functions that are not surjective.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yea I know its correct, but I wanted to know the reason. so Just so I know ( to make sure ): $n^{n}$ is the number of functions. $n!$ are the number of surjective functions.
Thanks :)
Can close thread if needed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's summarize the discussion in the comments.

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.  Your strategy of finding the number of functions $f: A \to A$ which are not surjective by subtracting the number of surjective functions from the number of functions $f: A \to A$ is correct.

A function assigns to each element of the domain an image in the codomain.  Since there are five possible images in the codomain for each of the five elements in the domain, there are $5^5$ functions $f: A \to A$.

Since the domain and codomain are the same, a function $f: A \to A$ can only be surjective if it is also injective since not every element in the codomain will be the image of an element in the domain unless each element in the domain is assigned a different image.  If $f: A \to A$ is injective, then there are five ways to assign $f(1)$, which leaves four ways to assign $f(2)$, three ways to assign $f(3)$, two ways to assign $f(4)$, and one way to assign $f(5)$.  Hence, there are $5! = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$
injective functions $f: A \to A$.  Since the injective functions $f: A \to A$ are also the surjective functions $f: A \to A$, there are $5!$ surjective functions $f: A \to A$.

Thus, the number of functions $f: A \to A$ which are not surjective is $5^5 - 5! = 3125 - 120 = 3005$.

Comment: Oh thanks, the explanation was usefull :)
Edit: thanks for the long explanation, I understand easily like that ( I prefer those, they are more elaborate that I can understand easily more )